# How to get rid of "extra" Future in Akka Stream Flow stages?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm working with Akka Streams and trying to use `Flow` stages for the most efficient way to describe an entire graph. In some of the stages I send messages to actors via the `ask` pattern.

Of course, when I use the `ask` pattern, I need to use `mapTo` in order to get the expected type for further processing.

Here is an example:

```
val runnableGraph = Source.single(CheckEntity(entity))
  .map { check =>
    (postgresActor ? check)
      .mapTo[CheckEntityResult]
      .map {
        case failure: PostgresFailure => Left(failure.message)
        case pEntity: PEntity => Right(check)
    }
  }
  .map {
    _.map {
      case Left(msg) => Future(Left(msg))
      case Right(check) =>
        (redisActor ? pEntity)
          .mapTo[CheckEntityResult]
          .map {
            case failure: RedisFailure => Left(failure.message)
            case rEntity: REntity => Right(rEntity)
          }
    }
  }
  .toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)

//The result's type is Future[Future[Either[String, Entity]]]
val futureResult = runnableGraph.run()
```

How do I get rid of the nested `Future` between the stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea to make it easier to propagate a `CheckEntity` element through the stream is to change your `CheckEntityResult` class to contain the corresponding `CheckEntity` instance. This would look something like this:

```
abstract class CheckEntityResult(entity: CheckEntity) extends Entity

case class PEntity(entity: CheckEntity) extends CheckEntityResult(entity)
case class PostgresFailure(entity: CheckEntity, message: String) extends CheckEntityResult(entity)

case class REntity(entity: CheckEntity) extends CheckEntityResult(entity)
case class RedisFailure(entity: CheckEntity, message: String) extends CheckEntityResult(entity)
```

Then, after adjusting your actors to handle these messages, you could use [`Source # ask`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-integrations.html#ask) and `mapAsync` (adjust the levels of parallelism as needed) to interact with the actors and to avoid the nested `Future` in the materialized value:

```
implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

val runnableGraph = Source.single(CheckEntity(entity))
  .ask[CheckEntityResult](parallelism = 3)(postgresActor)
  .map {
    case PostgresFailure(_, msg) => msg
    case PEntity(e) => e
  }
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 3) {
    case failureMsg: String => Future.successful(failureMsg)
    case e: CheckEntity => (redisActor ? e).mapTo[CheckEntityResult]
  }
  .map {
    case failureMsg: String => Left(failureMsg)
    case RedisFailure(_, msg) => Left(msg)
    case r: REntity => Right(r)
  }
  .toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)

val futureResult = runnableGraph.run() // Future[Either[String, Entity]]
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer is really comprehensive!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider converting your actor query into `Flow` along with `mapAsync` (with appropriate parallelism):

```
val postgresCheck = (check: CheckEntity) =>
    (postgresActor ? check).mapTo[CheckEntityResult]
      .map {
        case failure: PostgresFailure => Left(failure.message)
        case pEntity: PEntity => Right(check)
      }

val redisCheck = (e: Either[String, CheckEntityResult]) => e match {
    case Left(msg) => Future(Left(msg))
    case Right(checkResult) =>
      (redisActor ? checkResult).mapTo[CheckEntityResult]
        .map {
          case failure: RedisFailure => Left(failure.message)
          case rEntity: REntity => Right(rEntity)
        }
  }

val postgresCheckFlow = (parallelism: Int) =>
    Flow[CheckEntity]
      .mapAsync[Either[String, CheckEntityResult]](parallelism)(postgresCheck)

val redisCheckFlow = (parallelism: Int) =>
    Flow[Either[String, CheckEntityResult]]
      .mapAsync[Either[String, CheckEntityResult]](parallelism)(redisCheck)
```

With the converted flows, your runnableGraph can be assembled as below with result type `Future[Either[]]`:

```
val runnableGraph = Source.single(CheckEntity(entity))
  .via(postgresCheckFlow(parallelism))
  .via(redisCheckFlow(parallelism))
  ...
```

Comment: Big thanks for the idea to break the graph on separate stages before composing it :)